# CloudRail support for OneDrive For Business

Tags: cloudrail

We have used CloudRail to retrive files from OneDrive, Google Drive, Amazon S3 and Dropbox without hassle.

When we have tried to implement OneDrive For Business, we get an error

*'The app ID is blocked for access of the O365 Discovery Service'*

Does anyone know if this error comes from CloudRail or Azure? If I check the Azure history for the application, it is logging that my sign-n status is successful.

We have had multiple developers go through the setup instructions and get the client ID and secret with the same result.

We have now scaled our application to the example code on the CloudRail website and still the same problem.

Has anyone managed to get OneDrive For Business working with CloudRail?

If so, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Gary, this seems to be something on the Microsoft side since our existing integration we have set up for testing is still working. Maybe they have disabled something without telling anyone (as Microsoft likes to do). We are looking into this at the moment though.

Comment: Thanks. Must the person who adds the app be a Global Administrator for the tenant? I am currently only a Application Administrator which should have the required permissions to set up an app but I don't know about the discovery service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft, this is due to the O365 Discovery Service being depreciated. Existing application will still work but no new ones will.

CloudRail has updated their SDK to use Microsoft Graph instead of O365 and all is working.